# C#, enviar mail con Header personalizado

Tags: c#, headers

Necesito generar un correo electrónico cuya cabecera de "Content-Type" pueda controlar o personalizar, ya que por los requerimientos de la aplicación el Content-Type debe ir definido como:
"Content-Type:Application/TPL" donde TPL es un tipo de archivo que viaja adjunto y cuyo contenido es texto plano.

Con el siguiente código :

```
SmtpClient client = null;
client = new SmtpClient("IP servidor SMTP");
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("usuario","pass");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = from;
ContentType ct = new ContentType("Application/TPL");
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("path_to_TPL_file", System.IO .FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
Attachment data1 = new Attachment(fs, ct);
ContentDisposition disposition = data1.ContentDisposition;
disposition.Inline = true;
message.To.Add("destinatario@example.com");
message.Subject = "TPL";
client.Send(message);
```

Los intentos que he realizado, siempre obtengo "Content-Type:multipart/mixed;", lo cual impide que el destinatario valide el contenido recibido.

Siguiendo la documentación de SmtpClient, entiendo que el Content-Type no es una cabecera "personalizable", con lo cual no sé muy bien por dónde seguir.

Alguien ha tenido un problema similar.

Muchas gracias